# I cant symmetrize correctly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

so I'm trying to symmetrize these bones but it doesn't work, they don't flip to the other side, they stay on the same side as the ones on the left, even when i name it ".L" it doesn't seem to work.

[image: before symmetrizing]

[image: after symmetrizing]

even when I rotate the bones 90 degrees on the Z axis it still doesn't work

[image: there's a video showing it on the streamable link]

https://streamable.com/ihj8ii

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symmetrize option doesn't mirror bones on the axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194148/symmetrize-option-doesnt-mirror-bones-on-the-axis)

Comment: i have the cursor on the world origin and it doesn't seem to work, and the character it's on the center so... idk

Comment: https://streamable.com/xccv2f