# Mirrored object out of place

Tags: mirror-modifier

The mirrored cuff of the model I'm making has a different placement on the Y axis

Image for reference:

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening, probably touched some random hotkey.

Extra details: Blender 3.4.1 and beginner blender knowledge.

Comment: Can you add an image of the front view (1 on the numpad). You can also share your Blender file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there so that we can have a look and see what's going on..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symmetrize option doesn't mirror bones on the axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194148/symmetrize-option-doesnt-mirror-bones-on-the-axis)

Comment: To add to The Colamarine's answer, don't forget to apply the rotation of your object as well (Ctrl A)

Comment: Ookay everyone, thanks for your help! It was a rotation problem, now it's solved

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell by this one picture, but it sounds like your origin point is unaligned.

A simple fix is to enter Object mode, snap your 3D cursor to the center of the workspace using "Shift+C"

While still in object mode, select the "Object" dropdown at the top-left of your screen, hover over the option "Set Origin" and then click "Origin to 3D cursor"

Because you centered the 3D cursor earlier, this will now set your mirrored object's origin dead center in the workspace.